# How to bind a process to only physical cores in a cross system way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cross-platform, z3, hyperthreading

I’m using [a project where each time you double the number of threads](https://github.com/ConsenSys/mythril/pull/1372/files), you add between 40% to 60% overhead. As hyperthreading increases performance to a maximum of 30% this means, the program runs slower than in single thread mode on hyperthreaded systems.

The first steps seem to be simple.

- Get the number of threads on the system through `len(os.sched_getaffinity(0))`
- Restrict the number of threads through z3 parameters.
- Bind the threads to physical cores using `os.sched_setaffinity(0,mask)`.
- Leave smt solutions enabled for systems not containing Intel or amd inside `platform.machine()`.

However several problems arise for doing this.

- How to know if the system has hyperthreading enabled?
- Before using `os.sched_setaffinity(0,mask)`, how to know which cpu core numbers are physical or logical?

The problem is the program currently supports a wide number of platforms through python3: all Unixes, as well as Windows and Osx and Openvms while not forgetting PyPy.

Any patch to fix the problem shouldn’t spawn a new process nor add a non-included dependency nor drop support for some of the platforms above.

What can be a clean way to fix this?

Comment: See [QtCore.QThread.idealThreadCount()](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QThread.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QThread.idealThreadCount)

Comment: @VladimirBershov which isn’t supported on Openvms, so not cross platform. I’m thinking the solution should be pure python based in the current case.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin but this is a Python question! Not C++.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin the project itself isn t using binary code currently. I am doubting they would accept such a patch. Also performance wise, this would be a problem for PyPy.

Comment: @user2284570 have you considered  `psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)`, or is it not supported by some of your platforms?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin I don’t think they would accept an additional dependency just for that as they already tend favor single‑thread mode in general (until a huge proper rewrite without overhead is done using https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0554/ which would still require to serialize C objects which can’t be serialized). And Openᴠᴍꜱ isn’t supported. As a general rule, every supported platform can be considered listed in the question.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin I’m not aware of process control related dependencies. However, if you try `pip install mythril` you’ll see many dependencies. Most of the time things like dependencies of dependencies of dependencies. This project really requires a lot of packages.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin that’s a dependency hell. I’ve no idea on how to generate the full list. That’s why I stated it would be better the solution should only use the basic set of libraries that exists with all versions of Python (though I didn’t tell it was about python3.6) in an earlier comment.

Comment: I cleaned some of my comments that are not useful to clarify the question. I don't think that I might be able to help at this point. Best of luck!

Answer (score -1):

The [`loky` library](https://github.com/joblib/loky/blob/f15594a44420abfa9b398be7ff3c9180c2858bf4/loky/backend/context.py#L203) contains a fairly portable solution to this. It does spawn a process, and then caches the result -- so it's not like you're spawning a process more than once. Given this is the solution which backs popular libraries like `sklearn`, I would guess that it's almost as good as it gets.

Comment: It uses lscpu under the woods. An utility which don t exist on Openvms and Windows.

Comment: It has an alternative for windows. I'm sure you can add another elif to deal with openvms. If you find a better solution, you should definitely look at contributing it back to loky.