# How to detect E-cores and P-cores in Linux alder lake system?

Tags: linux, x86-64, intel, cpu-architecture, cpu-cores

How can I check particular cpu core belongs to P-core or E-core group? Is there any way to list information about Performance/Energy cores in a running Linux x86_64 alder lake system? Like, Printing any of the sysfs parameters?

Comment: I'd guess /proc/cpuinfo might show something, either in CPU frequency limits or in a model/stepping.

Comment: There is no unique data related to E or P cores in /proc/cpuinfo.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69955410/how-to-detect-p-e-core-in-intel-alder-lake-cpu/72245739#72245739
Please see my answer there

Answer (score 30, accepted):

We can identify which core has SMT (hyper-threading) enabled. Run:

```sh
lscpu --all --extended
```

This is the result for 12900K:

```sh
➜ lscpu --all --extended
CPU NODE SOCKET CORE L1d:L1i:L2:L3 ONLINE    MAXMHZ   MINMHZ
  0    0      0    0 0:0:0:0          yes 6700.0000 800.0000
  1    0      0    0 0:0:0:0          yes 6700.0000 800.0000
  2    0      0    1 1:1:1:0          yes 6700.0000 800.0000
  3    0      0    1 1:1:1:0          yes 6700.0000 800.0000
  4    0      0    2 2:2:2:0          yes 6500.0000 800.0000
  5    0      0    2 2:2:2:0          yes 6500.0000 800.0000
  6    0      0    3 3:3:3:0          yes 6500.0000 800.0000
  7    0      0    3 3:3:3:0          yes 6500.0000 800.0000
  8    0      0    4 4:4:4:0          yes 6500.0000 800.0000
  9    0      0    4 4:4:4:0          yes 6500.0000 800.0000
 10    0      0    5 5:5:5:0          yes 6500.0000 800.0000
 11    0      0    5 5:5:5:0          yes 6500.0000 800.0000
 12    0      0    6 6:6:6:0          yes 6500.0000 800.0000
 13    0      0    6 6:6:6:0          yes 6500.0000 800.0000
 14    0      0    7 7:7:7:0          yes 6500.0000 800.0000
 15    0      0    7 7:7:7:0          yes 6500.0000 800.0000
 16    0      0    8 8:8:8:0          yes 3900.0000 800.0000
 17    0      0    9 9:9:8:0          yes 3900.0000 800.0000
 18    0      0   10 10:10:8:0        yes 3900.0000 800.0000
 19    0      0   11 11:11:8:0        yes 3900.0000 800.0000
 20    0      0   12 12:12:9:0        yes 3900.0000 800.0000
 21    0      0   13 13:13:9:0        yes 3900.0000 800.0000
 22    0      0   14 14:14:9:0        yes 3900.0000 800.0000
 23    0      0   15 15:15:9:0        yes 3900.0000 800.0000
```

Now, look at the `CPU` column and `CORE` column. For example:

- CPU 0 and CPU 1 belong to CORE 0. Therefore, CORE 0 is a P-core with SMT.
- CPU 16 belongs to CORE 8. Therefore, CORE 8 is an E-core.

Note that this method will only work if you haven't explicitly disabled P-core's SMT in BIOS. If you disabled SMT in BIOS, you may look at the `MAXMHZ` column as suggested in Peter's comment.

Comment: Also, max MHz shows a clear difference, and would still work with SMT disabled.  IDK if there are Alder Lake models without turbo, or with the same cap for both core types.

Comment: what if hyperthreading is disabled on the system through bios option?

Comment: @Arrrow - Then, as Peter said, speed (MHZ) will be lower. Turbo or not, E-cores will always have a lower max speed.

Comment: another observation: each independent L2 cache 0~7 is shared by 2 CPUs of a P-core, but each of L2 cache 8,9 is shared by 4 CPUs of a E-core, consistent with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raptor_Lake