# What does os.cpus() return when the CPU has efficiency cores such as the i7-13700k?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cpu

When a CPU has multiple types of cores such as the i7-13700K with both performance cores and efficiency cores, what does [`os.cpus()`](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#oscpus) return?

Are they just shown as regular cores with a different speed value or are they indicated with some property that indicates they're a different type of core?

I don't happen to have access to such a CPU right now, but I am writing code that would like to know how many performance cores there are.

Comment: For what it's worth, on an M1 Mac (4 performance, 4 efficiency) it just shows 8 entries that look basically identical.

Answer (score 1):

`os.cpus()` returns an array of objects like you would expect.  It does not differentiate between performance/efficiency cores.

E.g.

```
[
  {
    model: '12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1280P',
    speed: 1996,
    times: { user: 75070, nice: 400, sys: 18870, idle: 55270240, irq: 0 }
  },
  {
    model: '12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1280P',
    speed: 1996,
    times: { user: 64530, nice: 900, sys: 10220, idle: 55291960, irq: 0 }
  },
  {
    model: '12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1280P',
    speed: 1996,
    times: { user: 85360, nice: 110, sys: 20670, idle: 55257350, irq: 0 }
  },
  * snip *
  {
    model: '12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1280P',
    speed: 1996,
    times: { user: 95930, nice: 400, sys: 23880, idle: 55250410, irq: 0 }
  },
  {
    model: '12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1280P',
    speed: 1996,
    times: { user: 21110, nice: 420, sys: 4700, idle: 55350410, irq: 0 }
  }
]
```

Comment: Are you saying that your example show efficiency cores?  And, there's no way to tell the difference with this API?  Shouldn't they at least show a different speed?

Comment: Would be interesting to know about ARM CPUs as well since the big/little architecture has been popular on ARM chips for a long time now.

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't think the OS may even know about E/P cores as most Intel Thread Director handles most of the intricacies.  Perhaps deep in the kernel there is some exposure but `os.cpus()` doesn't even differentiate  between cores and hyper threads.

Comment: Well, there are Windows programs (like AIDA64) that can identify e-cores so more information is knowable than `os.cpus()` chooses to share.  Relevant answers [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1735953/how-do-i-identify-which-cores-are-which-on-an-intel-hybrid-cpu) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71122837/how-to-detect-e-cores-and-p-cores-in-linux-alder-lake-system/71282744#71282744) that cover Windows and Linux (outside of nodejs).   So, apparently the answer is that `os.cpus()` does not show any  relevant information about a CPU core's capabilities.